# How to set Cross Synchronous in Node.js? (related Circular Dependency)

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, circular-dependency, cyclic-dependency

I have 2 different js files that depend each other like this:

```
// slider.js
'use strict';
import Loop from './loop.js';
export default class Slider {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.Loop = new Loop(this.elem);
        this.Loop.routine();
    }
    updateImage() {
        console.log(
            'Cross Synchronous Test: Updated images',
            'Called the function from loop.js'
        );
    }
}
let proSlider = new Slider('Number')
```

---

```
// loop.js
import Slider from './slider.js';
export default class Loop {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.Slider = new Slider(this.elem);
        this.Slider.updateImage();
    }
    routine() {
        console.log(
            'Cross Synchronous Test: references a group of actions',
            'Called the function from Slider.js'
        );
    }
}
```

My goal is to call the function `updateImage()` inside of `loop.js` and call the another function `routine()` inside of `slider.js` at the instance level, same time. So they can be separated as 2 different files, but still can access each other whenever I want it.

The problem is this throws an error called maximum callback stack.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I've read some of articles about Circular Dependency [#1](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/), [#2](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-break-a-cyclic-dependency-between-es6-modules-fd8ede198596) but the article #2 is mentioning based on typescript. I've changed the code w/o the typescript keywords and then the browser fires the same error.

```
// slider.js
constructor(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.getLoop();
}
getLoop() {
    return new Loop(this.elem).routine();
}
```

---

```
// loop.js
constructor(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.getSlider();
}
getSlider() {
    return new Slider(this.elem).updateImage();
}
```

Are there any ways to set cross-call functions in Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not a circular dependency of modules but an non terminating indirect recursion.

All unnecessary parts removed your code boils down to:

```
class Slider {
    constructor() {
       this.Loop = new Loop();
    }
}

class Loop {
    constructor() {
        this.Slider = new Slider();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the contructors for `Slider` and `Loop` are recursively calling each other in an endless loop that never terminates and creates an unlimited number of alternating instances of `Slider`, `Loop`, `Slider`, `Loop`, `Slider`, `Loop`, ...

One resort out of this dilemma could be that the second constructed instance gets an pointer to the first one and terminate the recursion:

```
class Slider {
    constructor(elem, loop) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.Loop = loop || new Loop(this.elem, this);
        this.Loop.routine();
    }
    updateImage() {
        console.log(
            'Cross Synchronous Test: Updated images',
            'Called the function from loop.js'
        );
    }
}

class Loop {
    constructor(elem, slider) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.Slider = slider || new Slider(this.elem, this);
        this.Slider.updateImage();
    }
    routine() {
        console.log(
            'Cross Synchronous Test: references a group of actions',
            'Called the function from Slider.js'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I try to access a third js file to `loop.js` like `slider.js` does? I've just tested and it worked but I wonder that is this still not related about Circular Dependency.  The relation map of those three would be like this: `slider.js` -> `loop.js` <- `button.js`.

Comment: The OP also has a circular dependency where A imports B and B imports A.